# OpenCV Error:Haarcascade xml Parsing error C++ Xcode

Tags: c++, xml, xcode, opencv

Having trouble parsing `Haarcascade` xml file. My code is simply

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <tracker/FaceTracker.hpp>
#include "main.h"



using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace FACETRACKER;


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

//Open ANY camera
VideoCapture captureDevice(-1);


// Something for the classifier to look at
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;


if (!face_cascade.load("./haarcascade_frontalface_pie1.xml")) {
    printf("Unable to load classifier  ");
    return 0 ;
}

// image containers for face classifier
Mat captureFrame;
Mat greyscalyFrame;

// Output window:
namedWindow("FTrackPro Output",1);

while(true)
{
    // capture aframe and convert to grey scale
    captureDevice>>captureFrame;
    cvtColor(captureFrame, greyscalyFrame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(greyscalyFrame, greyscalyFrame);

    // find faces and store them in the vector array "faces"
    std::vector<Rect> faces;

    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(greyscalyFrame,faces,1.1,3,CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE,Size(30,30));

    // draw a rectangle on all faces
    for (int i=0; i<faces.size(); i++){
        Point pt1(faces[i].x +faces[i].width,  faces[i].y+faces[i].height);
        Point pt2(faces[i].x,faces[i].y);
        rectangle(captureFrame, pt1, pt2, cvScalar(0,255,0,0),1,8,0);
        cout << "The value of data is: " ;

    }
      imshow("FTrackPro Output",captureFrame);
}
    // show the output

waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
return 0;
}
```

I have tried a heap of different XML files all with the same error :

**Output:**

```
OpenCV Error: Parsing error (./haarcascade_frontalface_pie1.xml(0): Too long string or a last string w/o newline) in icvXMLSkipSpaces, file /tmp/opencv-Yh1Wc4/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp, line 1838
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /tmp/opencv-Yh1Wc4/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp:1838: error: (-212) ./haarcascade_frontalface_pie1.xml(0): Too long string or a last string w/o newline in function icvXMLSkipSpaces
```

any help would be appreciated as i am out of my depth here, trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I uncovered the problem, i had the .xml files in the same directory as the executable and this error was occurring. 
Instead i moved the xml files to my home directory and referenced them from there.
originally:

```
if (!face_cascade.load("./haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")) {
    printf("Unable to load classifier  ");
    return 0 ;
}
```

Now :

```
  if (!face_cascade.load("/Users/$my username$/Documents/$$projectName/$$ProjectName/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")) {
    printf("Unable to load classifier  ");
    return 0 ;
}
```

Problem solved.